# flask oauth provider make_response TypeError

Tags: python, flask, response

im trying to run oauth provider from http://tech.shift.com/post/40299429203/implementing-a-python-oauth-2-0-provider-part-2.

but line:

```
flask_res = flask.make_response(response.text, response.status_code)
```

generates error:

```
flask_res = flask.make_response(response.text, response.status_code)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 616, in text
if not self.content:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 594, in content
self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 541, in generate
chunk = self.raw.read(chunk_size, decode_content=True)
TypeError: read() takes no keyword arguments
```

why? :|

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the solution for your question. But what you really want is an oauth2 server, right?

http://lepture.com/en/2013/create-oauth-server

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @kleopatra this can't be done on SO. A solution for OAuth2 provider is not that simple. It can't be solved in a simple answer.